# Rails) What Markdown Should I Use Now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcloth

I need the following features:

1. hard-wrap text
2. auto link (make urls into clickable links)
3. @name should turn into links to user/show action (I should be able to write this helper method)
4. prevent code injection

As far as I've learned, redcarpet doesn't seem to work properly, and I found *redcloth* to be the choice. But it seems a little outdated, and it doesn't provide filter_html or autolink options. I could install gems *sanitize* and *autolink* to use with redcloth but I believe there would be a better way.

Can anyone give me suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out the [html-pipeline gem](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline). It has filters for doing a lot of what you want and includes:

- `MentionFilter` - replace `@user` mentions with links
- `AutolinkFilter` - auto_linking urls in HTML
- `CamoFilter` - replace http image urls with [camo-fied](https://github.com/atmos/camo) https versions
- `EmailReplyFilter` - util filter for working with emails
- `EmojiFilter` - everyone loves [emoji](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/)!
- `HttpsFilter` - HTML Filter for replacing http github urls with https versions.
- `ImageMaxWidthFilter` - link to full size image for large images
- `MarkdownFilter` - convert markdown to html
- `PlainTextInputFilter` - html escape text and wrap the result in a div
- `SanitizationFilter` - whitelist sanitize user markup
- `SyntaxHighlightFilter` - code syntax highlighter with [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist)
- `TextileFilter` - convert textile to html
- `TableOfContentsFilter` - anchor headings with name attributes